# Multi-Nat on TP LINK AC1200

Tags: router, nat

I got a bit sick of the BT Business Smart Hub,its' slow and unreliable so on the advice of the guy in the computer shop i bought a TP-LINK AC1200.

My problem is that on the BT hub there is a Multi-Nat setting area which i can't find on the TP-Link router. In fact i can't find any way to set the tp link to use the gateway for my static ip range.

I have 5 static ip addresses from BT, does anyone know how to set these up in the TP-Link router so that each ip is mapped to a specific internal ip like i can on the BT hub?

Below is a screenshot of the router admin so you know which version it's using.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The tp link router ac1200 does not support multi NAT.